# Are there any methods for finding analytic solutions to this equation $(xy + \frac1e)e^{F(x,y)} = F(g(y)x , f(y))$

Tags: analysis, power-series, functional-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation $$
\left(xy + \frac1e\right)e^{F(x,y)} = F(g(y)x , f(y))
$$
for $F(x,y)$ where $f$ and $g$ are known functions, analytic in a neighborhood of $0$, with $g(0) = 1$ , $f(0) = 0$, and $f'(0) = 1$. I know how to find a formal power series
$$
F(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\ge0} a_{n,m} x^n y^m
$$
but this is a hassle to do and I don't that it will converge for any nonzero $x,y$, so I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to solve this type of equation.

For my particular application, $f$ can be any analytic function satisfying $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$, but $g$ will be related to $f$ by $f(y) g(y) = y$.

Comment: Do you have closed-form expressions for $f$ and $g?$ If so, could you please add them to the question?

Comment: For my application, $f$ can be pretty general as long as it satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$. $g$ actually depends on $f$, so I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that a very common method of solution is to plug numbers in and play around with the patterns that come up. Without knowing what $f$ and $g$ are, this is impossible.

Comment: Yes that's true. But for my application I actually do want to know for arbitrary $f$, so plugging in numbers is pretty tough.

Comment: Ok. Well, I hope you find a solution!

Comment: I would be interested in poking around with this functional equation, but only with actual $f$ and $g$ functions. You might find some patterns to help you out with the general case. Can you please post some specific $f$ and $g$'s?

Comment: You could try with a quadratic, like $f(x) = x + \frac12 x^2$. The first example I was working with was $f(x) = \exp(x) - 1$.

Comment: And what would $g$ be that case?

Comment: $g(y) = y/f(y)$ for my applications.